The "Dissolve"-Tool is not working anymore
To date, I have successfully applied the "merge vector-layers" and "dissolve" tools, available in the menu under "vector", to merge polygons and thereafter to dissolve the common inner boundary of the merged vector-layers. Now out of the sudden, the "dissolve" tool apparently is not working anymore, whatsoever. To address the issue, I have made sure, that no field is specified in the "dissolve"-panel, I have repaired the geometry of the merged vector-layer prior to dissolving, and have used the "dissolve related" tool. All with no avail. The inner boundary between my two merged vector-layers remains (see snapshot with red arrow).


You should add the software and version that you are using to your question.  It looks like QGIS based on the Layers format.  My guess is that your boundaries are not coincident; there is likely a small gap.  To be sure you could run the snap geometries to layer tool or run a v.clean with a snap tolerance sufficient to close any gap, then run the dissolve.

Try Select by expression overlay_disjoint( layer:='myLayer'), replace myLayer with the name of your layer. Features not intersecting any other will be selected. If there's  gap between the polygons in your screenshot, they will be selected

Thanks a lot, John. The "snap geometries to layer" tool solved the issue. I am working with QGIS-Version 3.34.3-Prizren.

@John, maybe you could add using Snap geometries to layer as an answer that can be accepted and voted?

My guess is that your boundaries are not coincident; there is likely a small gap. To be sure you could run the snap geometries to layer tool or run a v.clean with a snap tolerance sufficient to close any gap, then run the dissolve.
